# aspnetcore 2.2 api CORS policy

Tags: .net, cordova, .net-core

I've updated netcoreapp to 2.2 from 2.1 and cannot figure how to make CORS work again. Previously used following configuration:

```
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("App", builder =>
            builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
```

After upgrading to 2.2 `.AllowAnyOrigin()` is no longer supported. I've changed configuration to:

```
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("App", builder =>
            builder
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080", "ionic://localhost", "http://localhost") // (development, cordova-ios, cordova-android)
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
        ));
    }
```

Also I am using https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview plugin for cordova. Webview origin for android and ios are as following: http://localhost, ionic://localhost

I am receiving following error on Android:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-host-app.azurewebsites.net/api/user/profile' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
```

Request Headers:

```
:authority: my-host-app.azurewebsites.net
:method: OPTIONS
:path: /api/user/profile
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
accept-language: en-US,ru-RU;q=0.9
access-control-request-headers: api-version,deviceid,isapp
access-control-request-method: GET
origin: http://localhost
referer: http://localhost/
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; ONEPLUS A3003 Build/OPR1.170623.032; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/71.0.3578.99 Mobile Safari/537.36
x-requested-with: com.company.my-app
```

Response Headers:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: api-version,deviceid,isapp
access-control-allow-methods: GET
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost
date: Tue, 08 Jan 2019 11:52:54 GMT
request-context: appId=cid-v1:d20ad272-fa9b-4051-a89a-eea17ae49380
server: Kestrel
set-cookie: ARRAffinity=2252b451f5ef07b7d0d5027457bd2b71e73fb479db2cf5924161a51c2ec7b5;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=my-host-app.azurewebsites.net
status: 204
strict-transport-security: max-age=2592000
vary: Origin
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```

Same on iPhone but with ionic://localhost.

Answer (score 6):

I resolved by replacing `.WithOrigins()` to `.SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)`.

Comment: Who can explain difference between this two methods? Why it's helps?

Comment: late to the party, but as far as i get it, SetIsOriginAllowed with ((host => true) is the same as if you would have AllowAnyOrigin(), since the host is just mapped to be allowed.
You could use something like SetIsOriginAllowed((host => new Uri(host).Host == "localhost") to only allow browser-requests from localhost.

But i too don't really get why there are these two methods. My guess is that you won't have to write such "logic" with the new Uri(host).Host when using WithOrigins, since that just allows those set in its parameters.